# Linear Regression: Expectation Proof

Tags: statistics, regression

I found the following proof in my notes:

$E(Y_i) = E[\beta_0 + \beta X_i + \varepsilon_i] =\cdots= \beta_0 + \beta X_i$.  This does not seem right to me, however.  Why would $E(\beta_1 X_i) = \beta_1 X_i$?  I wonder if i might have written it down incorrectly, with the actual proof meaning to be for the estimated value Yi hat (I don't know how to code this unfortunately).  Does anyone recall this property of linear regression?

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\beta_i E X_i$? Your question needs some context...

Comment: It seems like what we are trying to show is that the expectation of a linear regression is a linear function of expectations but we may also be trying to show the proof shown on page 4 here: http://web.njit.edu/~wguo/Math644_2012/Math644_Chapter%201_part2.pdf

Comment: That proof shows the expectation of $Y_{i}$ is equivalent to the expectation of its estimate Yi hat

Comment: I actually think my answer is a bit more complete than the "accepted" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sort of regression problem, $X_i$ may be random in the sense that if you take another sample, all the $X_i$ values change, **but** one behaves as if one seeks the *conditional* expected value of $Y_i$ *given* $X_i$, so that in effect $X_i$ is treated as if it were constant rather than random.  And the $\beta$s are also being treated as constant.

Comment: Right, so in fact I was correct since it is in effect being treated as a constant.  I misunderstood before.

Answer (score 3):

If $Y_i=\beta_0+\beta X_i+\epsilon_i$, where $\beta_0$ and $\beta$ are constants and $\epsilon_i$ is an "error" random variable with mean $0$, then $E(Y_i)=\beta_0+\beta E(X_i)$.

Comment: This is what I thought, and what copper-hat mentioned above.  It seems likely I missed the E.  Thank you very much.  While I'm here, could I also ask: Why is it that the error has to be 'centered' or mean zero, and what is the importance of this property?  Do you think it is just to say 'remember, linearity of expectation works here too'?

Comment: If there is a systematic error, we would probably incorporate it in the $\beta_0$ term. Linearity of expectation would work in any case, we just use $E(\epsilon_i)$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  My other final question is: why in the linked document above, or in general, is E(Y) = E(Y'), that is, the estimated Y's expectation is the same as Y's expectation?  Is it that the variance is what's changing not the mean?

Comment: The least squares estimator is *unbiased*. That takes some proving.

Comment: Ohh, so that's what's meant by unbiased essentially.  The expected value of the estimate is unchanged.

Comment: An *estimator* is a random variable (like sample mean, or sample standard deviation) which is used to estimate a population parameter. The estimator is *unbiased* if it has expectation the population parameter. Unbiasedness is in general a desirable quality, though there are exceptions. For example, when we are estimating the variance of a normal, the population variance version that has $n-1$ in the denominator is unbiased, but the one with $n$ in the denominator has smaller variance (it is on average closer to the truth).

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I'm somewhat curious as to why you received a negative vote by the way.

Comment: If the voter left a comment, that could be helpful.

Comment: I've down-voted this answer but I'll up-vote it after the error is corrected: $E(Y_i)$ appears where $E(X_i)$ should be.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the typo. Fixed.

Comment: @user78504 : "Unbiased" doesn't mean the expected value of the estimator is "unchanged" (whatever that means$\ldots$); rather it means the expected value of the estimator is equal to the thing to be estimated.  Unbiasedness is at least somewhat overrated by the masses.  In some circumstances unbiasedness is a very bad thing.